# "На()ощупь"

Tags: орфография

Написал "наощупь" слитно, а Ворд выдает ошибку, предлагая раздельное написание. Что-то я засомневался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наречное сочетание "на ощупь" действительно пишется раздельно, как и многие другие, образованные от существительного на гласную, например  *в открытую.*. Но это не правило, а некоторые закономерности. Все наречные сочетания надо проверять по словарю. Наречие "наизнанку", например, пишется слитно.